# Uniform convergence of a series of complex functions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

> Prove the series of $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(z+n)^2}$$
>   converges uniforply on every set $K \setminus \Bbb{Z}$ such that $K \subseteq \Bbb{C}$ compact.

Here is my attempt:

I proved that the series converges pointwise for every $z \in \Bbb{C} \setminus \Bbb{Z}$

> Now since $K$ is compact exists $R>0$ such that $K \subseteq B(0,R)$
>
> We have 2 cases:
>
> $1)$ $K$  contains a finitely many  integers,say $m_1,...m_k$.
>
> Note that exists $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $N>2R$ so $N>\max\{|m_1|,...,|m_k|\}$ 
>   so we have for $z \in K \setminus \Bbb{Z}$ and for   $n \geq N$ that $|z+n| \geq n-|z|>n-R>0$  $$\sum_{|n| \geq N}\frac{1}{|z+n|^2} \leq \sum_{|n| \geq N}\frac{1}{(n-|z|)^2}\leq \sum_{|n| \geq N}\frac{1}{(n-R)^2}<\infty,\forall z \in K \setminus \Bbb{Z} $$
>
> By the Weierstrass $M-$test we have that the partial sums $\sum_{N \leq |n| \leq m}\frac{1}{(z+n)^2} \to^{m \to \infty} g(z)$ uniformly.
>
> We define the function  $G:K \setminus \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{C}$ as $G(z):=\sum_{|n|<N}\frac{1}{(z+n)^2}+g(z)$
>
> Let $m>N$.
>
> Then $$\sup_{z \in K \setminus \Bbb{Z}}| \sum_{|n| \leq m}\frac{1}{(z+n)^2}-G(z)|=\sup_{z \in K \setminus \Bbb{Z}}| \sum_{N \leq |n| \leq m}\frac{1}{(z+n)^2}-g(z)| \to^{m \to \infty}0$$
>
> $2)$ $K$ does not contain any integers.
>
> We do the same procedure.

Is this correct?

This question is from some old notes in complex analysis.

The same notes have been slightly modified and there is a different formulation  of this problem,where we must prove that the series converges uniformply for every compact $K \subseteq \Bbb{C} \setminus \Bbb{Z}$(which is different from $K \setminus \Bbb{Z}$ since this set may not be compact at all)

Is my proof correct,or is the problem wrong and that is why was modified?

Thank you in advance for your feedback.